# "Failed to download repository information"

Tags: apt, repositories

I am connected to the Internet but when i want to check for updates I get the following message:
 [image: "Failed to download repository information"]

Comment: Can you provide more information please, if you want to update, open terminal and type `sudo apt update` and add error details.

Comment: it is impossible to post de errors here there are to many characters

Comment: @peter  
How can I put a large text here?

Comment: @Tara Edit your original question - paste the log, select it, and then press the *preformatted text* button to format it.

Comment: If your connection is slow than it would happen sometimes.  It's better remove the connection and add  it.

Answer (score 1):

**Clean your cache and try again:**

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

If that isn't enough, try removing any offending repositories from `Applications menu > Software & Updates`. (If you need to install that, use `sudo apt install software-properties-common`.)